# Lots of ".class expected" and "not a statement"

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program to accept two 3x3 matrices, then add or multiply them. I'm getting lots of three different errors.

First, a bunch of ".class expected" errors when I try to create a string to display the whole matrix in these lines:

```
strA = "\n\n|" + r1a[];
strA += "|\n|" + r2a[];
strA += "|\n|" + r3a[];
```

It repeats when I do the other 2 iterations for strB and strC.
When I looked up this error, I found these as possibilities for why it's happening, none of which seem to be the issue when scanning my code:

```
Usually this is just a missing semicolon,
sometimes it can be caused by unbalanced () on the previous line.
sometimes it can be cause by junk on the previous line. This junk might be far to the right off the screen.
Sometimes it is caused by spelling the keyword if incorrectly nearby.
Sometimes it is a missing + concatenation operator.
```

<strike>My next issue is when I try to create the resulting matrix. I get a mixture of "not a statement" and "; expected" errors in this code:</strike>

```
r1c[] = r1a[] + r1b[];
r2c[] = r2a[] + r2b[];
r3c[] = r3a[] + r3b[];
```

The errors alternate; the compiler produces "not a statement" first with an arrow at the opening bracket of r1c[], followed by "; expected" with an arrow at the space between r1c[] =. The second and third occurrences simply move across the code, repeating the location (opening bracket, space). Thanks to tacp for this one being resolved!

This is how I declared all of my variables:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Matrices
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


       int i = 0;
       double[] r1a = new double[3];        //row 1 of matrix a
       double[] r2a = new double[3];        //row 2 of matrix a
       double[] r3a = new double[3];        //row 3 of matrix a
       double[] r1b = new double[3];        //row 1 of matrix b
       double[] r2b = new double[3];        //row 2 of matrix b
       double[] r3b = new double[3];        //row 3 of matrix b
       double[] r1c = new double[3];        //row 1 of matrix c
       double[] r2c = new double[3];        //row 2 of matrix c
       double[] r3c = new double[3];        //row 3 of matrix c

       String strInput,         //holds JOption inputs
       strA,                    //holds matrix A
       strB,                    //holds matrix B
       strC;                    //holds matrix C
```

I really am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's all of my code.. [code](http://txtup.net/PkbuD) :p
This is probably something extremely basic, but this is my first semester of coding, ever, in any language.. So my troubleshooting skills are minimal, as are my actual coding skills. haha
So, all of your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's `r1a[] + r1b[]` supposed to be? And adding `r1a[]` to a string?

Comment: Are you trying to append to class variable strings outside a method body? That will lead to some of the compiler errors you are seeing. Add to your question the ***signature*** of your class, and the declaration of all variables. You can omit the methods for brevity's sake.

Comment: This is how you declare multidimensional array For ex: `double[ ][ ] anArray = new double[5][5]`. This will create 5 rows and 5 columns. And refer them with their Row-Column combination.

Comment: r1a[] + r1b[] is supposed to be adding the 2 arrays together... I'm trying to add r1a[] into the string so it can be displayed, not trying to do math with it.

The only method I have is main, the only thing outside of the class is the import javax.swing.JOptionPane; statement.

I'm not sure what you mean by the signature of the class.

Comment: please post full class code. I think you are doing calculations outside method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 strA = "\n\n|" + r1a[];
 strA += "|\n|" + r2a[];
 strA += "|\n|" + r3a[];
```

You need to specify type for `strA` and index to access array elements for `r1a, r2a` and `r3a`

Similarly, you need index to access array (they are arrays representing rows of matrix):

```
r1c[] = r1a[] + r1b[];
r2c[] = r2a[] + r2b[];
r3c[] = r3a[] + r3b[];
```

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
   r1c[i] = r1a[i] + r1b[i];
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by specify type and index?

Also, is there not a simple way to add the whole array to another array? Must I add the individual doubles to each other, via the for loop for example?

Comment: @Riqqu type of variables indicates what kind of operations can be applied on them. for example, int a indicates that a is int and can have +,-,*,/ or % operations on it. so strA should be string type. In Java, to add two arrays to another, you should use for loop or  for each loop.

Comment: I have declared type.

String strInput,
strA,
strB,
strC;

Comment: @Riqqu OK. you need index to access array elements, for example: A is an array, A[] will not access the elements directly, you need to specify index, say, A[0] to access to access the first element, etc.

Comment: Ahhh! You've reminded me of class! I forgot, but our professor mentioned in passing memory leaks, which I believe is what I was trying to do by taking an array and trying to put it into another array. haha Thanks, I'll see if that fixes some errors.